# How can I reindex monthly indexes to weekly indexes in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch-5, logstash-configuration

I have currently monthly indexes in the following format:

```
fabricxxx-access-log-monthly-2018.01
..
..
fabricxxx-access-log-monthly-2018.04
```

I have decided to move away from monthly indexes to weekly indexes due to data compliance issues.

Can I leverage the "reindex-api" to convert the existing monthly indexes to weekly indexes?

I have seen a lot of related questions on different forums, but they all discuss about how to convert daily indexes to monthly. My use case is quite the opposite.